# How can I efficiently add X modulo Y to every element in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, modulo

Say I have a very large array of values between 1 and 180, and these are in an array of `uint8`s (which can go as high as 255). I would like to add 90 (modulo 180) to each value:

```
original = np.array([1, 2, 3, 170, 171, 172], dtype=np.uint8)
modified = (original + 90) % 180
```

Unfortunately, this yields an incorrect result, because the larger numbers overflow their uint8 integers in the first step when adding 90: 170 + 90 = 260 which is greater than 255.

```
# (170 + 90) % 180 is 80, not 4 :(
array([91, 92, 93,  4,  5,  6], dtype=uint8)
```

I'm operating in a very performance-sensitive context, and my input list is very large. As such, I would like to avoid the penalty of converting this array to a larger datatype, and I would like to use efficient operations (e.g. avoiding looping through the array and processing each value individually).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Using ```import numpy```and ```numpy.mod(numpy1arr + 90, numpy2arr)```. In your case I assume that numpy2arr will be n-vector of 180.

Comment: `>>> ((original.astype(np.uint16) + 90) % 180).astype(np.uint8)
array([91, 92, 93, 80, 81, 82], dtype=uint8)` ? Or you don't want to cast?

Comment: @furkanayd: this yields the identical problem, because the overflow happens in the `numpy1arr + 90` step.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta thanks for the suggestion, that would yield the correct result. However, as I mention in the description this array is very large and casting to a larger datatype is very expensive.

Comment: This is an interesting question although, for practical purposes, keep in mind that solutions that create several intermediate arrays (masks, each opeartion, etc) may be more expensive than upcasting (which in the end just takes twice the original size for 16 bits, if you reuse the original array to store the downcasted result). Advanced indexing (selecting a subset of an array with a mask) is also expensive. I'd benchmark the solutions here against the simple upcasting solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One very simple option, since you are dealing with `uint8`, is to simply compute in advance the result for each possible value in the array and use it:

```
import numpy as np
original = np.array([1, 2, 3, 170, 171, 172], dtype=np.uint8)
value_map = ((np.arange(256) + 90) % 180).astype(np.uint8)
modified = value_map[original]
print(modified)
# [91 92 93 80 81 82]
```

The good thing about this is it does not take any additional memory beyond the 256-element `value_map`, and for any larger array you will be saving most of the computation too.

Running a time benchmark against casting:

```
import numpy as np

def add_val_mod_cast(a, val, mod):
    return ((a.astype(np.uint16) + val) % mod).astype(np.uint8)

def add_val_mod_map(a, val, mod):
    value_map = ((np.arange(256) + val) % mod).astype(np.uint8)
    return value_map[a]

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(256, size=10_000_000).astype(np.uint8)
val = 90
mod = 180
print((add_val_mod_cast(a, val, mod) == add_val_mod_map(a, val, mod)).all())
# True
%timeit add_val_mod_cast(a, val, mod)
# 72.6 ms ± 2.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit add_val_mod_map(a, val, mod)
# 40.8 ms ± 606 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea for very large arrays. Do you really need to entire range of 256?

Comment: @Divakar Ah right maybe not if input values are in `[0, mod)` already... although it makes a difference of hundreds of bytes at most, and it "fixes" input values out of the expected range (or not fails for them), so one may or may not keep it I guess...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast the array to `np.unit16`:

```
>>> ((original.astype(np.uint16) + 90) % 180).astype(np.uint8)
array([91, 92, 93, 80, 81, 82], dtype=uint8)
```

If you want to achieve this using only `uint8` you can just double increment only those elements that are bigger than `255-90`:

```
>>> modified = (original + 90) % 180
>>> modified[original >= 255-90] += 256-180
>>> modified
array([91, 92, 93, 80, 81, 82], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Wow, your second solution looks like exactly what I'd need. I had no idea you could conditionally select numpy array elements like that. Testing it out now, but I suspect this will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with some math and without upcasting -

```
def add_with_modulus(original, addval, modulusval=180):
    v = original + addval
    v[modulusval-original<=addval] += 256-modulusval
    return v
```

Usage : `add_with_modulus(original, addval=90, modulusval=180)`.

Comment: v2 doesn't quite seem to work. `add_with_modulus_v2(np.array(range(180), dtype=np.uint8), 100)` results in a list with values going up to 200.

Comment: @Mala Yup, that was a bug indeed in the mask checking. Check out the edits please.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
```

Assign a random numpy array of integers of size (10, 10) having elements whose maximum value can be 255.

```
np_array = np.random.randint(255, size=(10, 10))
```

Add 90 to each element and do modulus on it.

```
np_array = (np_array + 90) % 180
```